# Expectation value of factored polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that any polynomial over the complex numbers can be factored, i.e.

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0=b_0(x-b_1)(x-b_2)\dots(x-b_n).$$

Consider the set of all polynomials of degree $n$. Suppose I draw a random polynomial from this set; on average, what is the value of $b_0$? Can we even define an expectation value on this set?

Comment: You can define a continuous expected value as an integral, but what ring are the polynomials a part of? $\mathbb{C}[x]$? Also, $b_0=a_n$.

Comment: I don't know anything about abstract algebra. I didn't realise that $b_0=a_n$, but that does make sense

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with polynomials; since, as mentioned in the comments, we just have $b_0 = a_n$, you are just asking what the average value of a random real (or perhaps complex) number is.

The answer is that this average is not well-defined, because there is no such thing as a "random real (or complex) number," at least not without further elaboration. Formally, there is no canonical [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) on the real (or complex) numbers; you have to choose one (e.g. a [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)) and any choice will make some numbers more likely than others. There is no "uniform" distribution in this setting that you can default to.